# Resizing (smaller) jpg Images in a batch without losing quality

Tags: image, resize, photoshop

I have a few hundred jpg images which i would like to resize in a batch.

The jpgs are 150k and above but once i make them smaller the quality is lost. how i batch resize and keep the quality?

I have tried irfanview but it loses quality. I have also tried resizing by photoshop and the quality is still the same, it goes blurry.

Any help will be muchly appreciated

Comment: What size in pixels are the originals and what are you resizing them to?

Comment: Not good fit for SO... maybe superuser.com... Also if find a way to decrease size of an image without decreasing quality you should immediately patent it and sell for some insane amount of money :).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with linux utility `convert` from imagemagic package. Run from the shell while in directory with pictures:

```
for i in *jpg; do convert -resize 100 $i new_$i;done
```

`-resize 100` will ask to resize image to the height of 100px. Also you can try to add `-quality 80` to optimize it a bit.

Comment: linux? Sounds bit to complicated for me. do you know of another option?

Comment: imagemagic is available and runs beautifully under Windows too. I use it myself. But I also use Irfanview and the quality achieved by that is not any worse, *if* you make sure you select the settings properly!

Comment: yeh, you can use imagemagic on windows. Pretty simple. You can see the bat file example at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15487

Comment: If i just resize the image in photoshop i get the same quality, Is there a way of resizing images which will not cause anyloss but just make the image smaller? size of the file can stay the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to batch resize a lot of images smaller, you can write an special Photoshop action for this.

It can be done in few minutes:

1. Open Actions panel (Window-> Actions or Alt+F9).
2. Select a folder in the Actions panel (or create a new one).
3. Open one of images you want to resize.
4. Click "Create new action" icon (the second icon from the right, at the bottom of panel).
5. Click "Begin recording" icon (the second icon from the left).
6. Resize the image (Ctrl+Alt+I or Cmd+Opt+I for Macs). You also can apply some sharpen filter if you want to make the image more crisp and sharpen.
7. Click "Stop recording" button (the icon on the left side).
8. Open File->Automate->Batch, choose an action you just created, file format you need and a folder for exporting - and press OK.

That's it :) Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use IrfanView "Batch Conversion/Rename" Tool or use this little batch below.

1. Include IrfanView Path in Windows System Variables to call it anywhere directly
2. Create batch file to resize, sharpen and crop your images to your newWidth (adjust parameters accordingly)

   > start i_view32.exe C:\Path\To\Your\Images*.jpg /resize=(newWidth,) /aspectratio /resample /sharpen=33 /crop=(0,0,newWidth,newHeight,4) /convert=C:\NewPath\To\Your\Images\small$X.jpg

Parameters explanations:
crop=> (x,y,newWidth,newHeight,startCorner)
convert=> $X - file directory index